# Find the count of a element tag in XML response in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

1 . Im doing XML parsing from a url.IN the XML response , how can I get the length of element tag ..
Eg :

```
<Company>
   <Id>1</Id>
   <name>A</name>
</Company>
<Company>
   <Id>2</Id>
   <name>B</name>
</Company>
```

IN this how can I get the no of 'Company' tags i.e 2

---> I got some GUID value in array when parsing XML and I am taking it in a string variable.But when I compare a particular value with the string variable it is not getting compared..Couldnot get where im going wrong ?
My array is

```
(
{
Id="84a6c6f6-b018-4f0e-8da4-c64bf76be764"
}
)
```

now Im taking it in string variable like this :

```
nam=[[arr objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Id"];
```

But if the result of arr is 
    (
    {
    Id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    }
    )

and if I compare

```
if(nam=@"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
{
   //do something

}
```

But here my cursor is not going to if stmnt if though Id is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000..How can i compare it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy if you the name of tag, as while parsing, in a function "didStartElement" you can do so

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Company"])
        companyCount++;
}
```

Please let me know if that works for you

Comment: I want to know the total number of Company tags in XML response..i.e 1 or 2 or 0 or .....

Comment: including </Company> tags, or only <Company>?

Comment: whenever the Parser encounters <Company> tag it will obey the condition written in if and will increment the variable companyCount and this way you can easily get the number of times the desired tag is in the xml response

Comment: BTW the best way to compare the strings is with "isEqualToString" method, you should not be using == to compare strings

Answer (score 2):

Just use `[nam isEqualToString:@"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"]` in order to compare strings.

PS. Even if you *could* compare strings with equals sign, your code still wouldn't work since `=` denotes assignment, where `==` checks for equality. (So in your example you just assign the string to `nam` variable)

---

EDIT: (Just noticed that there were 2 questions)

For the element count, you could either increment an integer inside `didStartElement` delegate method (as the other guys said) or have an `NSMutableArray` and add the objects there (for example it would make sense to have `Company` class instances from your parsed XML. After that `myCompanies.count` should give you the number of companies.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer of your first question. You can simply take an integer variable and initiate it to zero.
If you are using NSXMLParser then in

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

check for the equality of tag named "Company" using function isEqualToString: and if the condition is satisfied then increment the count.

At the end of parsing the counter will be having the count of occurrence of "Company" tag